# Moving array elements over one position

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a homework assignment where we're supposed to create a list of integers, and allow the user to INSERT an integer at a given position in the list. The list should essentially move all integers over one position in the array, then insert the integer that the user input at the index they chose.

So let's say I have an array of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and I want to put 9 in index 1, the array should then be {1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

I thought I figured out the solution with this function:

```
void *INSERT(int count, int userNum, int index, int array[]){ //Accepts count of array, users number, users index, and array
    int tempIndex = index;
    index--;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < count; counter++)
    {
        array[tempIndex] = array[tempIndex-1];
        tempIndex++;
    }
    array[index] = userNum;
}
```

Here is what I have in the main function:

```
int index = 0; //Hold users index selection
int userNum = 0; //Hold users number

int n = 10;

int a[n] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *ptr = a;

cout << "Enter a number to insert: ";
cin >> userNum;
cout << "Enter an index: ";
cin >> index;
INSERT(n, userNum, index, ptr);//call insert function (Accepts count of array, users number, users index, and array)

int listNum = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << listNum << ". " << a[i] << "\n";
    listNum++;
}
```

However, this is the output after printing the array:

```
1. 1
2. 9
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
6. 2
7. 2
8. 2
9. 2
10. 2
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here that could be causing this output. If I remove the -1 from the INSERT functions for loop like this(commented it out to make it more clear on what's being changed):

```
void *INSERT(int c, int n, int i, int a[]){ //Accepts count of array, users number, users index, and array
    int x = i;
    i--;

    for(int r = 0; r < c; r++)
    {
        a[x] = a[x/*-1*/];
        x++;
    }
    a[i] = n;
}
```

I get the following output with the above code, which is what I'd expect but not what I need. I can post the entire code if needed as well, but I think this explains where the problem is. Thanks in advance for the help

```
1. 1
2. 9
3. 3
4. 4
5. 5
6. 0
7. 0
8. 0
9. 0
10. 0
```

Comment: @littleadv I know, I'm not proud of the variable names. I'm usually much better about this :facepalm:

Comment: the point is that if you name your variables properly you'll find the bug immediately.

Comment: Also, if you work through this by hand, you'll see what's happening

Comment: @littleadv I don't believe the bug has anything to do with the variable names lol, but I understand where you're coming from. I honestly only used these variable names for testing purposes.

Also though, isn't it bad practice to use the same variable names in the main function and outside functions? I ran out of ideas for variable names to use for functions outside of main

Comment: The bug doesn't have to do anything with the names, for sure. You not seeing it does.

Comment: @littleadv there, I renamed the variables to make things clearer. I don't see how this helps me though. I guess I'll have to work through this on pen and paper but in my head I still see this working in the way that I'm intending

Comment: Work with pen and paper! Yes, that's absolutely what you should be doing! Please do that before you read the answers.

Comment: Okay, I feel dumb after working it out, I definitely see the issue now :facepalm:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, just change your insert function to this -

Here we first shift the values to next index in the array and then perform insertion of respective element

```
void *INSERT(int c, int n, int i, int a[]){ //Accepts count of array, users number, users index, and array

    for(int r = c-1; r >= i; r--)
    {
        a[r+1] = a[r];
    }
    a[i] = n;
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the way my code works you'd actually need to use a[i-1] = n; after the for loop for it to work perfectly.
  `void *INSERT(int count, int userNum, int index, int array[]){ //Accepts count of array, users number, users index, and array
 
    for(int i = count; i >= index; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    }
    array[index-1] = userNum;
    
}`

Comment: Okay got it. I just had the insertion part in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be somewhat controversial because instead of directly solving your assignment for you I'm just telling you how to debug it so you can solve it yourself.

So fixed your code for you:

```
//Accepts count of array, users number, users index, and array
void *INSERT(
        int array_size,
        int number_to_insert,
        int insert_at,
        int numbers[]){
    int moving_index = insert_at;
    insert_at--; // Why are you doing this?

    for(int r = 0; r < array_size; r++)
    {
        // moving_index was initialized as insert_at
        // What happens when insert_at is 0?
        // What happens when moving_index >= array_size?
        // Who knows...
        numbers[moving_index] = numbers[moving_index-1]; 
        // You're incrementing moving_index.
        moving_index++;
        // What would numbers[moving_index-1] be now?
    }
    numbers[insert_at] = number_to_insert;
}
```

Once you answer my questions, I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: I am doing insert_at-- to get the actual index. If you see my output examples, the user should be entering 1-10. I then decrement to get the actual arrays index since arrays begin at 0. That said, insert_at should never be 0. It should also never be greater than array_size because of this. I'll use input checking before the insert_at and number_to_insert variables are ever passed to the INSERT function.

Comment: @Chance there's only one question left unanswered ;-)

Comment: Which question is that? You mean "What would numbers[moving_index-1] be now?". I already worked out the loop with pen and paper so I do see the issue now

Comment: even after understanding the problem I'm not sure I know the best way to approach it... The only other method I would think of would be to create an identical array, then loop to add those elements into the existing one

Comment: @Chance it shouldn't be identical if you don't want to lose items... I don't know what they taught you already about memory management, but C does allow `realloc`ating arrays in-place so that you wouldn't need to copy *all* of it.

Comment: Turns out the best way to do it is close to what @NIKITA RATH posted. I tried their way originally but couldn't get it to work until making a couple changes

Comment: @Chance that's a good way to do it, but notice that each time you lose the last array item. So if that's ok then it's good code.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. This shouldn't be a problem because technically nothing should be at the end unless the list is full. If the list is full I will return an error. I've only hard coded the list in this way to make testing easier. I will only be printing elements that are actually in the list rather than the full array in the finished program